# What is the use of * in printf?

Tags: c, printf

I have a this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int n = 5;
    clrscr();
    printf("n=%*d", n);
    getch();
}
```

The output which I got is: `n= 5`. Why is there a space? How is it generated? What is the use of `*` in the code?

Comment: No problem, as you can see people are happy to help: however, it's always better to make _some_ effort to figure things out yourself.  Your _search engine of choice_ is your friend!

Comment: Can I get more examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned in the [C Manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

The answer is already given by [Richard J. Ross III](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii). Just quoting again what is said from the manual.

> The *width* is not specified in the *format* string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

Consider this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a,b;
    float c,d;

    a = 15;
    b = a / 2;
    printf("%d\n",b);
    printf("%3d\n",b);
    printf("%03d\n",b);

    c = 15.3;
    d = c / 3;
    printf("%3.2f\n",d);
}
```

The output would be:

```
7
   7
007
5.10
```

You can see here, how the `printf` function can be used for formatting output. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Where can I find more? What is the best book for C?

Comment: Best book for beginners would be **Let us C** *by Yashawant Kanetkar*. :) You can check out the book at http://books.google.co.in/books?id=7HrjAAAACAAJ

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is available in my university. Will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, read the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/):

> `*`:
>
> The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

However, you appear to be using it wrong. The proper way to use it would be like this:

```
printf("n=%*d", 2, n);
```

Comment: @PriyankaR that's a difficult question. Many People will say K&R are the best, because they were the first.

Answer (score 3):

With this `*`, you can set the width of your print with a variable.

Comment: I've seen your answer too late (I was writing). Should I delete it ?

Comment: It's up to you, personally, I would, since I'm worried about the people who will come with a torrent of downvotes. But hey, it's up to you (I +1'd you anyway).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Where did you get the idea people should downvote similar answers ?!

Comment: @cnicutar It happens all of the time in the objective-c circles, and sometimes it bleeds to other places...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's preposterous. There's no "perfect" answer. Multiple answers, stating the same basic fact can be mighty useful in understanding an issue.

Comment: @cnicutar I agree, but I've been (and seen others) destroyed many times, so I like to play cautiously.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII So if you agree, why comment "Dupe of my answer" ?